# javascript promise after foreach loop with multiple mongoose find

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, promise

I'm trying to have a loop with some db calls, and once their all done ill send the result. - Using a promise, but if i have my promise after the callback it dosent work.

```
  let notuser = [];


  let promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

  users.forEach((x) => {


    User.find({
      /* query here */
    }, function(err, results) {
        if(err) throw err

    if(results.length) {
          notuser.push(x);
          /* resolve(notuser)  works here - but were not done yet*/ 
        }
    })
  });

  resolve(notuser); /*not giving me the array */

}).then((notuser) => {

return res.json(notuser)

})
```

how can i handle this ?

Comment: Map array of query promises and use `Promise.all()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is a function called `findManyUsers` which does what you're looking for.  Mongo find will return a promise to you, so just collect those promises in a loop and run them together with `Promise.all()`.  So you can see it in action, I've added a mock User class with a promise-returning find method...

```js
// User class pretends to be the mongo user. The find() method
// returns a promise to 'find" a user with a given id
class User {
    static find(id) {
        return new Promise(r => {
            setTimeout(() => r({ id: `user-${id}` }), 500);
        });
    }
}

//  return a promise to find all of the users with the given ids
async function findManyUsers(ids) {
    let promises = ids.map(id => User.find(id));
    return Promise.all(promises);
}

findManyUsers(['A', 'B', 'C']).then(result => console.log(result));
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you take a look at [async](https://www.npmjs.com/package/async) it's a great library for this sort of things and more, I really think you should get used to implement it.

I would solve your problem using the following

```
const async = require('async')

let notuser = [];

async.forEach(users, (user, callback)=>{
     User.find({}, (err, results) => {
          if (err) callback(err)

          if(results.length) {
               notUser.push(x)
               callback(null)
          }
     })
}, (err) => {
     err ? throw err : return(notuser)
})
```

However, if you don't want to use a 3rd party library, you are better off using promise.all and await for it to finish.

**EDIT: Remember to install `async` using `npm` or `yarn` something similar to `yarn add async` -- `npm install async`**

Comment: `err ? throw err : return(notuser)` doesn't really make sense in an asynchronous callback

Comment: I am just following his logic, he wants to throw an error when an error exist. The goal behind my example is to show the user of async

Answer (score 0):

I used @danh solution for the basis of fixing in my scenario (so credit goes there), but thought my code may be relevant to someone else, looking to use standard mongoose without async. I want to gets a summary of how many reports for a certain status and return the last 5 for each, combined into one response.

```
const { Report } = require('../../models/report');
const Workspace = require('../../models/workspace');

// GET request to return page of items from users report
module.exports = (req, res, next) => {
  const workspaceId = req.params.workspaceId || req.workspaceId;
  let summary = [];

  // returns a mongoose like promise
  function addStatusSummary(status) {
    let totalItems;
    let $regex = `^${status}$`;
    let query = {
      $and: [{ workspace: workspaceId }, { status: { $regex, $options: 'i' } }],
    };

    return Report.find(query)
      .countDocuments()
      .then((numberOfItems) => {
        totalItems = numberOfItems;
        return Report.find(query)
          .sort({ updatedAt: -1 })
          .skip(0)
          .limit(5);
      })
      .then((reports) => {
        const items = reports.map((r) => r.displayForMember());
        summary.push({
          status,
          items,
          totalItems,
        });
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        if (!err.statusCode) {
          err.statusCode = 500;
        }
        next(err);
      });
  }

  Workspace.findById(workspaceId)
    .then((workspace) => {
      let promises = workspace.custom.statusList.map((status) =>
        addStatusSummary(status)
      );
      return Promise.all(promises);
    })
    .then(() => {
      res.status(200).json({
        summary,
      });
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      if (!err.statusCode) {
        err.statusCode = 500;
      }
      next(err);
    });
};
```